# Find binary's in $PATH

Tags: go

I am looking for a function to find a binary in all folders which are available in $PATH.
I know i can use os.Getenv("PATH") but it returns:

```
path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Which needs to be processed.
Ideally function like this: FindBinary("ntpq") and it will return the path + binary name and false when not found in path.
Does anybody have a ready function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`LookPath`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath) function from the `os/exec` package:

```
path, err := exec.LookPath("fortune")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("installing fortune is in your future")
}
fmt.Printf("fortune is available at %s\n", path)
```

Comment: This answer needs to be fleshed out but it's correct.